# Error al ejecutar npm install, npm ERR! code ENOENT

Tags: npm, git-bash

Deseo hacer `npm install` para un proyecto ya con sus dependencias unicamente es instalarlas pero genera este error y no comprendo la razón.

Error al ejecutar `npm install` en terminal git bach y desde la terminal en visual de power shell:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\cc\Downloads\PI-Videogames-main\PI-Videogames-main/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\cc\Downloads\PI-Videogames-main\PI-Videogames-main\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-09T05_40_23_197Z-debug-0.log

cc@LAPTOP-MNL4BJKR MINGW64 ~/Downloads/PI-Videogames-main/PI-Videogames-main (main)
$ ^C

cc@LAPTOP-MNL4BJKR MINGW64 ~/Downloads/PI-Videogames-main/PI-Videogames-main (main)
$ ^C
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega la estructura de la carpeta: `C:\Users\cc\Downloads\PI-Videogames-main\PI-Videogames-main` Saludos :D

Comment: npm no encuentra el archivo `package.json` para instalar cosa, fijate si hay una carpeta `src` `api` `client` `service` `server` etc.. ahí debe estar

Comment: No creo que la pregunta tenga relación con git, por cierto.

Comment: @eftshift0 git bash es un terminal incluido en la instalación de git para windows

Comment: si, pero las preguntas que se etiquetan con `git` es porque tienen que ver con problemas de git (el sistema de control de versiones), no con bash (que tampoco creo que tenga relación con bash).

Comment: Ya ajusté la etiqueta para que sea `git-bash` y no `git` asi que todo gud.

Comment: un pifie en el git clone te puede dejar en otro lado, el prompt del mingw64 indica (main) asi q eso no es, un script en git bash para windows puede concatenar mal las carpetas ( os path separator comillas cuando hay espacios y sarasa ) el path del syscall está bien para git bash asi q eso tampoco es. de las causas mas comunes lo mas probable es que en el repo haya un nivel mas ( una subcarpeta ) donde esté el package.json , seguramente la documentación del repo es poco clara